# R use str_extract (stringr) to export a string between "_"

Tags: r, extract, stringr

I have some strings in a vector like:

```
x <- c("ROH_Pete_NA_1_2017.zip",
   "ROH_Annette_SA_2_2016.zip",
   "ROH_Steve_MF_4_2015.zip")
```

I need to extract the names out of this `strings (Pete, Annette, Steve)` 
I would like to do this, in a loop and with `str_extract()`

all Strings starts with `ROH_` but the length of the names are different and also the strings behind.

I would like to use `str_extract()` but I'm also happy for other solutions

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably better off with `str_match`, as this allows capture groups. 
 So you can add the `_` either side for context but only return the bit you are interested in.  The `(\\w+?)` is the capture group, and `str_match` returns this as the second column, hence the `[,2]` (the first column is what `str_extract` would return).

```
library(stringr)
str_match(x,"ROH_(\\w+?)_")[,2]

[1] "Pete"    "Annette" "Steve"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution with **`str_extract`**:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=_).+?(?=_)")
# [1] "Pete"    "Annette" "Steve"
```

---

You can also use **`gsub`** in base R:

```
gsub("^.+?_|_.+$", "", x)
# [1] "Pete"    "Annette" "Steve"
```

Comment: For others looking here, the `str_extract` solution uses positive lookbehind and positive lookahead. Read more [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

try the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(a,"_", simplify = T)[,2]
[1] "Pete"    "Annette" "Steve"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base function sub.

```
sub("ROH_([[:alpha:]]+)_.*","\\1",x,perl=T)

[1] "Pete"    "Annette" "Steve"
```